# Failed to send http request, boost::beast::http::read() hangs

Tags: c++, http, networking, boost

I tried to modify this boost [sample code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/quick_start/http_client.html) to send an simple http request, for whatever result. Originally it will give me a 404 as expected.

```bash
> .\httpclient.exe www.baidu.com 80 /fake/target

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 209
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2022 14:02:25 GMT
Server: Apache

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /fake/target was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Howerver, when I tried to set more fields in request, it hangs on `http::read`. I was trying to send some data (a json string defined as `body` below) to my server api, but since it hang there, I have no idea what to modify.

My entire code is here

```cpp
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;     // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;       // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;        // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp = net::ip::tcp;           // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

#define PBLOG_INFO(a) do { std::clog << (a) << std::endl; } while(0);

// Performs an HTTP GET and prints the response
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        // Check command line arguments.
        if (argc != 4 && argc != 5)
        {
            std::cerr <<
                "Usage: http-client-sync <host> <port> <target> [<HTTP version: 1.0 or 1.1(default)>]\n" <<
                "Example:\n" <<
                "    http-client-sync www.example.com 80 /\n" <<
                "    http-client-sync www.example.com 80 / 1.0\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        auto const host = argv[1];
        auto const port = argv[2];
        auto const target = argv[3];
        int version = argc == 5 && !std::strcmp("1.0", argv[4]) ? 10 : 11;

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        net::io_context ioc;

        // These objects perform our I/O
        tcp::resolver resolver(ioc);
        beast::tcp_stream stream(ioc);

        // Look up the domain name
        auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        stream.connect(results);

        std::string uid = "sample-uid";
        int pid = 12345;
        std::string body = "{ \"uid\": \"" + uid + "\", \"pid\" : " + std::to_string(pid) + " }";

        // Set up an HTTP GET request message
        http::request<http::string_body> req{ http::verb::post, target, version };
        req.set(http::field::host, std::string(host) + ":" + port);
        req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
        req.set(http::field::content_type, "application/json");
        req.set(http::field::body, body);
        req.set(http::field::content_length, std::to_string(body.length()));
        req.set(http::field::version, "HTTP/1.1");
        req.set(http::field::accept, "*/*");
        req.set(http::field::accept_encoding, "gzip, deflate, br");
        req.set(http::field::connection, "keep-alive");

        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "\n\nhook api request:\n" << req;
        PBLOG_INFO(oss.str());
        oss.clear();

        // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
        http::write(stream, req);

        // This buffer is used for reading and must be persisted
        beast::flat_buffer buffer;

        // Declare a container to hold the response
        http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;

        // Receive the HTTP response
        std::cout << "before read" << std::endl;
        http::read(stream, buffer, res);
        std::cout << "after read" << std::endl;

        // Write the message to standard out
        std::cout << res << std::endl;

        // Gracefully close the socket
        beast::error_code ec;
        stream.socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

        // not_connected happens sometimes
        // so don't bother reporting it.
        //
        if (ec && ec != beast::errc::not_connected)
            throw beast::system_error{ ec };

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is like this

```bash
> .\httpclient.exe www.baidu.com 80 /fake/target

hook api request:
POST /fake/target HTTP/1.1
Host: www.baidu.com:80
User-Agent: Boost.Beast/330
Content-Type: application/json
Body: { "uid": "sample-uid", "pid" : 12345 }
Content-Length: 38
Version: HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

before read
```

I was supposed to know what's wrong with my request (headers or body), but it simply hang there so I can't find out the problem with my request data.

Can anyone help me on this? Many thanks!

Comment: I think it might be your request for a keep-alive connection. Change it to "close".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you! this is exactly the problem! I was setting these fields like a offline mock tool called Apifox... the connection field is exactly the problem!